# How to know if facebook sharing is completed using FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am sharing an link on facebook using following code:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2://"]]){
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
    }
    else {
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser; //or FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic
    }
    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twipply.com"];

    dialog.shareContent = content;
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    [dialog show];
```

it returns to didCompleteWithResults delegate in following cases:
1) post is done from safari webPage. ( in both cases cancel and done).
2) post successfully from fb app.

Now how to know whether the link is actually posted or not. In case of safari, we get postID. But in case of app postID is not returned. So how should I know that it has been actually posted or not.

I have used following code but it always enters to the if condition and not getting postID is case of posted through app. this results to "The post didn't complete, they probably switched back to the app".

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults :(NSDictionary *)results {

     NSURL *fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"];
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbURL]){
        if (results[@"postId"]) {
            NSLog(@"Sweet, they shared, and Facebook isn't installed.");
            actionTypeSearch = kActionTypeSharing;
            sharingType = @"0";
            [self sendRequestToWeb];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"The post didn't complete, they probably switched back to the app");
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sweet, they shared, and Facebook is installed.");
        actionTypeSearch = kActionTypeSharing;
        sharingType = @"0";
        [self sendRequestToWeb];
    }


    NSLog(@"FB: SHARE RESULTS=%@\n",[results debugDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

 if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
        [self shareVideoOnFacebook];
    } else {
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logOut];  //very important line for login to work
        [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                          handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error) {
                                              if(!error) {
                                                  [self shareVideoOnFacebook];
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {

                                              }
                                          }];
    }
- (void) shareVideoOnFacebook
{
    __weak SharingViewController *weakSelf = self;

    NSString *pathFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathFile];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3L];

    [params setObject:videoData forKey:@"video_filename.MOV"];
    [params setObject:@"Title for this post." forKey:@"title"];
    [params setObject:@"Video App" forKey:@"description"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection connection, id result, NSError error) {
         [spinnerView endRefreshing];
         spinnerView.hidden = true;
         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;

         if (!error) {
             //video posted
             [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Send Successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
         }
         else{
             NSString *strError=@"";
             NSString *strWaringMesssage;
             if ([[[[Common sharedCommon]errorList]allKeys] containsObject:strError])
             {
                 NSString *strWaring=[[[Common sharedCommon]errorList] objectForKey:strError];
                 strWaringMesssage=[dictTemp objectForKey:strWaring];
             }
             else
             {
                 NSString *strWaring= DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE;
                 strWaringMesssage=[dictTemp objectForKey:strWaring];

             }
             ErrorViewController *objErrorViewController =[[ErrorViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ErrorViewController" bundle:nil];
             objErrorViewController.strErrorNumber = strWaringMesssage;
             [weakSelf presentViewController:objErrorViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to know if data has been posted or not without publish_actions permission? As I need to send it for review to facebook for Publish_actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the results dictionary in the following `FBSDKSharingDelegate` callback.

```
- (void)sharer:(id <FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
```

If the results dictionary is empty, the user didn't actually post to Facebook. If they did, it should contain at least the `postID`.